# How to Implement different HTML background images based on different controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, methods, background, controller

Using Rails (4.1.4) and Ruby (2.1.2), what would be the most DRY way to implement different background images based on different controller actions? Would I need to move HTML code  tags out of /app/views/layouts/application and move them into the separate view pages or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `content_for` method. [described here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method)

Essentially, in your layout you might have

```
<body class="<%= yield @body_class %>">
```

Then in your views you could do

```
<% content_for :body_class do 'class-name' end %>

<!-- regular view HTML -->
```

Answer (score 1):

*Just use **different classes on your element based on your action name** and then apply different background images on those classes*

Rails has **controller_name and action_name helpers to get your controller name and action name** so you can do:

```
<div class="<%= 'class_name' if action_name == 'show' %>">
</div>
```

And if you want to use the same class name as your controllers action then you can do

```
<div class="<%= action_name %>">
</div>
```

**If you are using same layout for different controllers then you can utilize rails controller_name with action_name to make a unique class**, something like:

```
<div class="<%= controller_name action_name %>">
</div>
```

Then use css accordingly, lets say you have home controller and new and show action then you can do

```
.home.show{
   background: image-url("pic1.png");
 }

 .home.new{
   background: image-url("pic2.png");
 }
```

Comment: You can run into issues here when you have multiple controllers with the same action name though.

Comment: @JustinLicata only if you'll use same layout for different controllers and rails also has controller_name helper to distinguish that so that will take care of it

Comment: Yes adding the `controller_name` will help. Your original answer did not specify using the controller_name to help combat the possible dup which is why I commented. And I would assume here that he is using the same layout for different controllers. No worries though, I prefer this answer over mine as mine has redundancy.

Comment: @JustinLicata yeah i know thanks! i was just updating my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamic class name on the element (which should have bg img)

```
# your '.html.erb' template
<body class="<%=controller_name%>-<%=action_name%>">
  ...
</body>


# your css file
// for user_controller's 'new' action
body.user-new {
  background-image: url(http://cdn.topshelfcomix.com/catalog/covers/any_empire_cover_sm_lg.jpg);
}

// for profiles_controller's 'show' action
body.profile-show {
  background-image: url(http://mrzine.monthlyreview.org/2011/images/latuff_egypt_by_any_means_necessary_a.gif);
}
```

That's it.. Enjoy!!

Comment: Great answers from Erik, Mandeep and RAJ. This answer from RAJ looks like it will do it for me, as all 3 answers were similar implementations. Thanks, guys!